# Img element to fill container width unless maximum height is reached using pure CSS

Tags: html, css, image, layout

I am trying to use CSS to set the size of an image. I want the image to fill the width of the container, so `width: 100%` would do it (even if the original img width is smaller).

However, the source can contain both portrait or landscape images. In case of long portraits, instead of filling the width I would like to center the image within the container given a maximum height.

I've tried the obvious:

```
width: 100%;
max-height: 250px;
```

But obviously it forces the width and the image is distorted. If I set max-width instead of width, smaller images than the container won't fill the space even in the maximum height is not reached.

Is there any way in pure css to tell the image to fill the container, unless some height is reached?

Comment: I'd give a try to https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/

Comment: ^ or consider the image as background instead

Comment: maybe setting `height: 250px;` and `width:auto;` or, `max-height:250px;` `background-size: cover;` `width: auto;`